# How do I create separate Javascript windows for each form in one HTML document

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to learn some php/html and the lot that comes with it. I used [this tutorial](http://www.peterkropff.de/site/tutorials/php_mysql.htm) as a start. It is in german so I'm not sure how useful the link will be to you.

It had no problems with the tutorial itself, which basically contained to create 3 php-pages - each doing one of the following: deleting, inserting, updating data on different tables in a database using mysql. For each action a simple window is opened through a js-function to manipulate the sql statements. My problem arose when i tried to make every type of processing data (insert/delete/update) availably on all php-pages/tables. My first attempt was to make the insert function available to table "hersteller", which technically worked, but everytime I press one of the buttons that run the .js and open a window it displays two html-forms instead of only the one i want to show. I can't seem to get rid of it. I know i could put the html-form in a different php-page, or (possibly?) change the visibility of the form, but I really would like to know why it doesnt work.
Any help is appreciated.

tl;dr: creating a window through js that i want to display a html form depending on which buttons have been clicked, but it ALWAYS shows all/both htmls-forms in the php-page.

Here's some code

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>PHP / MySQL - Tutorial 1</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="files/cms.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="files/menue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navi">
  <h1>Navigation</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php?tabelle=hersteller">Hersteller</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?tabelle=produkte">Produkte</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?tabelle=kunden">Kunden</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<?php 
require ('inc/db.inc.php');

if ($_GET['tabelle'])
{
  switch ($_GET['tabelle'])
    {
case 'hersteller': $table = 'hersteller';
                       $field = 'zulieferer';
                       break;
case 'produkte'  : $table = 'produkt';
                   $field = 'produkt';
                   break;
case 'kunden'    : $table = 'kunde';
                   $field = 'doktor';
                   break;
default          : die ('Manipulationsversuch!');
}
$query = 'SElECT id, '.$field.' AS list FROM '.$table;

$result = mysql_query ($query) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)) {
    $list[] = $row;
}

include ('inc/functions.inc.php');
$code = '<div class="ausgabe"><h1>'.ucfirst($_GET['tabelle']).'</h1>';

$code .= 
        '<p class="menue">
            <a href="#"
            onclick="fenster('."'".$_GET['tabelle']."',
            '".$_GET['tabelle']."'".');">
            Neuen Datensatz einpflegen
            </a>
        </p>';
$code .= showList ($list, $_GET['id']);
$code .= '</div>';
echo $code;
print_r ($list);
}
?>'
</body>
</html>
```

menue.js

```
  function fenster1(datei, param)
  {
    window.open('data/' + datei + '.php?tabelle=' + param + '&type=insert', datei, 'scrollbars=yes, rezisable=yes, width=500, height=300');
  }
  function fenster2(datei, param) {
      window.open('data/' + datei + '.php?tabelle=' + param, datei, 'scrollbars=yes, rezisable=yes, width=500, height=300');
  }
```

functions.inc.php

```
<?php
  function showList ($list, $id) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count ($list); $i++) {
            $ausgabe .= '<p>
                            <a href="#" onclick="fenster2('."'".$_GET['tabelle']."','".$_GET['tabelle'].
                                '&id= '.$list[$i]['id']."'".');">
                                Ändern
                            </a>';

            $ausgabe .= '<a href="#" onclick="fenster2('."'".$_GET['tabelle']."','".$_GET['tabelle'].
                            '&id='.$list[$i]['id']."'".');">
                            Loeschen
                        </a>';
            if ($id == $list[$i]['id']) {
                $ausgabe .= '<span class="show">';
            }
            $ausgabe .= $list[$i]['list'];
            if ($id == $list[$i]['id']) {
                $ausgabe .= '</span>';
            }
            $ausgabe .= '</p>';
        }
        return $ausgabe;
    }
?>
```

hersteller.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hersteller</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../files/cms.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <?php
    require ('../inc/db.inc.php');

    if ($_GET['id'] != NULL) {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM hersteller WHERE id = ' . $_GET['id'];
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $hersteller = mysql_fetch_row($result);

        echo $query . "\n";
    } else if ($_POST['update']) {
        $query = 'UPDATE hersteller SET
                zulieferer = \'' . $_POST['zulieferer'] . '\',
                telefon = \'' . $_POST['telefon'] . '\',
                fax = \'' . $_POST['telefax'] . '\',
                strasse = \'' . $_POST['strasse'] . '\',
                plz = \'' . $_POST['plz'] . '\',
                ort = \'' . $_POST['ort'] . '\'
                WHERE
                id = ' . $_POST['id'];

        echo $query . "\n";

        $update = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    echo '<body';
    if ($update['update']) {
        echo ' onload="window.opener.location.href=' . "'" . '../index.php' .
        '?tabelle=' . $_GET['tabelle'] . '&id=' . $_POST['id'] .
        "'" . '; window.close();"';
    }
    echo '>';

#require ('../inc/db.inc.php');

    if ($_POST['datensatz']) {

        $query = 'INSERT INTO hersteller VALUES 
          (' . "'','" .
                $_POST['zulieferer'] . "','" .
                $_POST['telefon'] . "','" .
                $_POST['fax'] . "','" .
                $_POST['strasse'] . "','" .
                $_POST['plz'] . "','" .
                $_POST['ort'] . "'" .
                ')';

        echo $query . "\n";

        $result['datensatz'] = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        echo $query . "\n";
    }

    echo '<body';
    if ($result['datensatz']) {
        echo ' onload="window.opener.location.href=' . "'" . '../index.php' .
        '?tabelle=' . $_GET['tabelle'] . "'" . '; window.close();"';
    }
    echo '>';
    echo $_GET['type'];

    switch (isset($_GET['type'])) {
        case 'insert': echo
            '<form action="hersteller.php?tabelle='.$_GET['tabelle'].'&type=insert" method="post">
                <p>
                    <label for="zulieferer">Zulieferer</label>
                    <input type="text" name="zulieferer" class="feld" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="telefon">Telefon</label>
                    <input type="text" name="telefon" class="feld" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="telefax">Telefax</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fax" class="feld" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="strasse">Straße</label>
                    <input type="text" name="strasse" class="feld" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="plz">PLZ, Ort</label>
                    <input type="text" name="plz" class="feld" style="width: 60px;" />
                    <input type="text" name="ort" class="feld" style="width: 230px;" />
                </p>
                <p style="text-align: center">
                    <input type="hidden" name="datensatz" value="'.$_GET['id'].'" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Eingeben" />
                </p>
            </form>';
        case 'update': echo 
            '<form action="hersteller.php?tabelle='.$_GET['tabelle'].'&id = '.$_POST['id'].'&type=update" method="post"> 
                <p>
                    <label for="zulieferer">Zulieferer</label>
                    <input type="text" name="zulieferer" class="feld" 
                    value="'.$hersteller[1].'" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="telefon">Telefon</label>
                    <input type="text" name="telefon" class="feld" value="'.§hersteller[2].'" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="telefax">Telefax</label>
                    <input type="text" name="telefax" class="feld" value="'.$hersteller[3].'" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="strasse">Strasse</label>
                    <input type="text" name="strasse" class="feld" value="'.$hersteller[4].'" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="plz">PLZ, Ort</label>
                    <input type="text" name="plz" class="feld" style="width: 60px;" value="'.$hersteller[5].'" />
                    <input type="text" name="ort" class="feld" style="width: 230px;" value="'.$hersteller[6].'" />
                </p>
                <p style="text-align: center">  
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$_GET['id'].'" />
                    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Einggeben" />
                </p>
            </form>';    
    }

?>



</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the long-ish post, feel free to tell what is obsolete/missing. And again - any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: changed documents to the new version.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am aware of that, but I'm at the level where I'm trying to figure out how things work together. I'll deal with that once I have a grasp of that. At least i know now what to look out for.

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems your tutorial is quite old: it uses `mysql_*` functions, which are deprecated (for quite some time already). You may want to look for a better tutorial.
For your problem: in your `hersteller.php`, there is nothing that tells the file which `form` to show, and which one to hide.
Based on the `GET` parameters, you can use `if` or `switch` statements around your different forms, to show or hide the respective forms.

Comment: Hey @Burki thanks for your reply. Regarding the tutorial: I think he sample code is quite old and still beeing used for the basic tutorials. If I remeber correctly the author even mentions that somewhere. However it has last been updated a year ago, so i thought it not to be that bad. I thought it to be sufficent for the most basic steps i try to learn right now.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, but i pretty busy the last days. I followed your suggestion to use a `switch` function based on the `get` parameter (I edited the `hersteller.php` in my first post). In the `case` part I try to display the html-`forms` with `echo` - I got one case for each html-`form` - but it still shows both html-`forms`, even if the right parameter is shown in the url. I think I am overlooking something basic, but I just can't find it. Sorry to bother you with this.